# Typeorm query builder don't work when orderBy and distinctOn use different columns

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to get some data from repository using query builder (typeorm) and i want to order items by 'trip.publishedAt' column and to remove duplicates with 'trip.id' column but i got this error message.

"
[Nest] 556   - 07/11/2023, 4:52:24 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions +2257ms
QueryFailedError: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
"

This is my code

```
async getDestinationTrips(destinationId: string) {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('tripDestination')
      .innerJoin('tripDestination.destination', 'destination')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('tripDestination.trip', 'trip')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('trip.image', 'image')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('trip.travelTagMappers', 'travelTagMappers')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('travelTagMappers.travelTag', 'travelTag')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('trip.creator', 'creator')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('trip.items', 'items')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('items.tripActivity', 'tripActivity')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('tripActivity.activity', 'activity')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('tripActivity.gallery', 'gallery')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('gallery.image', 'galleryImage')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('creator.image', 'creatorImage')
      .where('destination.id = :destinationId', {
        destinationId,
      })
      .orWhere('destination.parent_id = :destinationId')
      .andWhere('trip.publishedAt is not null')
      .orderBy('trip.publishedAt', 'DESC')
      .distinctOn(['trip.publishedAt'])
      .getMany();
```

When I remove orderBy it works but i need to keep order.

Comment: This is not a query builder problem. If you try to execute query like as 'select distinct a from table order by b', you will also receive error in PostgreSQL. So you must use ordered fields in distinct list. Second way you can use subquery, firstly use order by after then distinct or versa.